# How can i make a DropdownButtonFormField that supports multi selection and searchable

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

am coding a sign up page that contains some data about the users and one of the data is a huge list the user have to choose form, so i made a searchable DropdownButtonFormField2 but then i wanted the user to have the ability to select more than 1 item at the same time, but i can't figure it out..

this is the code of my current DropdownButtonFormField2

```
Widget _buildPropertyDropdown() {
    return DropdownButtonFormField2<String>(
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please select a unit.';
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),
      isExpanded: true,
      hint: Text(
        'Select client property',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14,
          color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
        ),
      ),
      items: PropertyListAndPhase()
          .propertyList
          .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem(
                value: item,
                child: Text(
                  item,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
              ))
          .toList(),
      value: _selectedProperty,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedProperty = value.toString();
        });
      },
      onSaved: (value) {
        value = _selectedProperty.toString();
      },
      buttonStyleData: const ButtonStyleData(
        height: 25,
        width: 500,
      ),
      dropdownStyleData: const DropdownStyleData(
        maxHeight: 200,
      ),
      menuItemStyleData: const MenuItemStyleData(
        height: 40,
      ),
      dropdownSearchData: DropdownSearchData(
        searchController: _searchController,
        searchInnerWidgetHeight: 50,
        searchInnerWidget: Container(
          height: 50,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 8,
            bottom: 4,
            right: 8,
            left: 8,
          ),
          child: TextFormField(
            expands: true,
            maxLines: null,
            controller: _searchController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              isDense: true,
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 10,
                vertical: 8,
              ),
              hintText: 'Search for an item...',
              hintStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        searchMatchFn: (item, searchValue) {
          return (item.value.toString().contains(searchValue));
        },
      ),
      //This to clear the search value when you close the menu
      onMenuStateChange: (isOpen) {
        if (!isOpen) {
          _searchController.clear();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

i tried to look at the documentation of the DropdownButtonFormField2 but i couldn't resonate with it.

Comment: [customizable_multiselect_field](https://pub.dev/packages/customizable_multiselect_field) may help you.